# Multiple entries inside validationEngine()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I need to validate a form and need custom error messages to be displayed on different fields while they are all 'required' fields.
My code is not working, and I don't know where it is gone wrong. I'm new to JQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form_message").validationEngine('attach', {
        onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
            if(status == true){
                submitMessage();                
            }
        }   
    });

    $("#form_message").validationEngine(
            {'custom_error_messages': {
            // Custom Error Messages for IDs
            '#toWhom' : {
            'required': {
            'message': "Fill this field."
            }
            }               
        }
    });

});
```

I tried many ways of placing these two code segments, but they dont' work together. If I comment out the first part, the 2nd works, and vice versa.

```
<form id="form_message" name="form_message" action="" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="toWhom">To :</label>
    <input id="toWhom" name="toWhom" type="text" value="" onClick="switchTo('selectEmployee');"
    class="validate[required]">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="submitBut">&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="submitBut" id="submitBut" type="submit" value="<%= gs("submit") %>" class="BUT">
</p>
</form>
```

Appreciate if someone can point out the fault.

Answer (score 0):

try with jquery validation with name

add link

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

code:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        toWhom: "required"
}
 messages: {
        toWhom: "Please enter your name"
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way I got it working, after adjusting some curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working :) posting answer maybe someone else might need it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#form_message").validationEngine({'custom_error_messages': {
        '#toWhom' : {
            'required': {
                'message': "Fill this field!"               
            }   
        }
    }   
    ,
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if(status == true){
            submitMessage();                
        }
    }});    

});
```